# python, disnake - Как отправить картинку по url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, disnake

Делаю Дискорд-бота с помощью библиотеки **disnake**. Не понимаю, как отправить изображение, имея  только его *URL*, при этом **не** используя стиль *Embed*?

Также вылезает эта ошибка:
`disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`. Гуглил и не понял. Помогите исправить.

```
@bot.slash_command(name='pictures', description='Поиск картинок в Интернете.')
async def pictures(inter, request : str, count=3):
    parser = YandexImage()

    pictures = []

    for url in parser.search(request):
        cicles = 0
        pictures.append(url.url)
        cicles += 1
        if cicles == count:
            break

    await inter.send(f'Результат по вашему запросу: {request}', file=disnake.File([pictures]))
```

Если что библиотека `YandexImage` просто парсит картинки по HTTP-запросу из Яндекса и заносит их *URL* в список `pictures`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отправить изображение по URL, можно воспользоваться методом await inter.send(file=...) и передать ему объект типа io.BytesIO, полученный с помощью requests:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='pictures', description='Поиск картинок в Интернете.')
async def pictures(inter, request: str, count=3):
    parser = YandexImage()

    pictures = []
    cicles = 0

    for url in parser.search(request):
        pictures.append(url.url)
        cicles += 1
        if cicles == count:
            break

    for picture_url in pictures:
        response = requests.get(picture_url)
        image_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)
        await inter.send(file=disnake.File(image_bytes, filename='image.png')))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: отметьте ответ, если помог

Comment: да, помогло, только теперь у меня бесконтрольно много файлов. Мне бы сделать так, что отправлялось столько же файлов, сколько и `count`.

Comment: поправил, попробуй

Comment: спасибо. помогло

Comment: только как пометить. Я тут просто новенький.

Comment: галочку нажать на ответе

Comment: готово. ещё раз спасибо)